# How can I modify a a contentcontrol by its tagname?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I have several controls in an open document, and i'm struggling to modify their values using interop.Word. Is it possible to get a contentcontrol via it's tagname, or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

This is the code i'm using:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl cc = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl)document.SelectContentControlsByTag("TheTagName");
cc.Range.Text = "My Data";
```

Comment: `SelectContentControlsByTag` returns an array, so you're casting to the wrong data type. (Aren't you getting an error?!) You need to cast to Word.ContentControl**s**. If you need only the first member, then `cc[1].Range.Text`

Comment: So are you saying that in this case, it'll return an array containing that single control identified by the tag? Can you give me the exact code I need please, I think i'm doing it wrong, i've cast it to a ContentControls array, however it won't let me access it, says the syntax is wrong...

Comment: So, it appears my suggestion worked, in the end? A tip: When you come back and say "It doesn't work, the syntax is wrong" please provide the full error message and the code that generated it. Often, we can guess correctly, but not always...

Comment: I tried your code of cc[1].Range.Text, but the compiler was telling me that cc couldn't be accessed by [n]. So while you were correct in your diagnosis of the problem, your solution to access the element in the contentcontrol array was incorrect i'm afraid. I posted an answer showing the method that I was able to access the element in the end.

Comment: Not a problem and I saw your change. Just wanted to make sure everything was OK and give you a tip about follow-up info :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me now:

```
object control = 1;
document.SelectContentControlsByTag("TagName").get_Item(ref control).Range.Text = "MyText";
```